# Size of a class increases if destructor is included

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, destructor, new-operator, sizeof

```
class MyClass {
        int data;
        public:
        MyClass() : data(0) { /*cout << "Ctor" << endl;*/}
        void* operator new(size_t sz) { cout << "Size in new: " << sz << endl; void* s = malloc(sz); return s; }
        void* operator new[] (size_t sz) { cout << "Size: " << sz << endl; void* s = malloc(sz); return s; }

        void operator delete(void* p) { free(p); }
        void operator delete[](void* p) { free(p); }
        ~MyClass() {}
};
int main() {
        // your code goes here
        MyClass* p = new MyClass[1];
        delete[] p;
        cout << "Size of class: " << sizeof(MyClass) << endl;  
        return 0;
}
```

Here I am overloading the new and delete operator. The strange behaviour what I observe here is if I include the destructor size passed to new operator is increased by 4 and size of MyClass is still 4 which is obvious.

The output I am getting is with destructor:
Size: 8
Size of class: 4

The output I am getting is without destructor:
Size: 4
Size of class: 4

Why is it so that inclusion of destructor increases the size?

Comment: Try creating an array of 100 objects and see if you get 800 bytes allocated or 404, and see if that tells you anything.

Comment: ^^^ Also a side point, you should probably use C++ global operator new rather than C malloc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think about how `delete[]` works. If there's no destructor, most likely all it needs to do is pass the address to `free`. But if there is a destructor, it has to know how many elements are in the array so it knows how many times to invoke the destructor. So some extra space is needed to hold the size of the array.

Comment: So in this case to hold how many objects we are creating delete operator creates a variable for itself to hold that value?

Comment: @Gaurav Not really a variable, just some extra space in the allocated block.

Comment: If I am not providing a destructor, won't it call the default destructor provided by the compiler, and in this case also it should show size+4 to hold number of objects. @David Schwartz

Comment: @Gaurav The default destructor optimizes to nothing at all. The answer to "why doesn't the compiler do something it doesn't have to do" is "because it's smart".